Нужна ли запятая
Нужна ли запятая в первой части предложения:

Закусил удила(,)и в путь - ты ж принц, а не хрыч болотный.

Я бы, наверное, вместо запятой тире поставила, но там же тире во второй части уже есть...

Не думаю, что нужна запятая. Само по себе "в путь" не обладает информативностью отдельного предложения. Плюс там ещё есть "и". Выглядит экстра нагруженным  с запятой.
